# How to convert a date to "mm/dd/yy" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to convert date from `Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 EST 2013` to `12/23/2013`.

`MyDate` is the variable to be converted which has the first format.

```
function checkrecord(reptdate) {
    if (reportdate != '' ){
       $('#tblearn tr[id]').each(function () {
          var _v_reptdate = $.trim($(this).find('[colname = "daterpted"]').html());
          if (reptdate == _v_reptdate)  {
             alert('do something');
          }
       });
    }
}
```

In other word I want to convert reptdate which is in Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 EST 2013 format to _v_reptdate which is in "12/23/2013" format. I want to convert parameter because this function is called from many other functions.

Comment: Can you add 'plugins' to your website? if so, I recommend using [http://momentjs.com/](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: What formatDate method?

Comment: using pure JS: `var d = new Date("Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 EST 2013"); var dateString = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyDate = "Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 EST 2013";
var d = new Date(MyDate);
var formatted = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Without using a library, you are going to have inconsistent results from browser to browser and different regions. A good library to check out is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: that's why we can always use `getMonth`, `getDate`, `getFullYear` and concatenate altogether to get the result although it's a bit long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about formatDate, but you can do it yourself:

Se my example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZYW8/4

```
function formatDate(dateString) {
    var m = dateString.substr(4,3);
    var d = dateString.substr(8,2);
    var y = dateString.substr(-4,4);
    var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    var m_i = months.indexOf(m) + 1;
    if(parseInt(m_i) < 10) m_i = "0" + m_i;
    return d+"/"+m_i+"/"+y;
}
```

However, I don't know how you're getting the value to be converted. If you're getting the value (your example `Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 EST 2013`) from Date.toString(), the code above may fail in different browsers.

So, if you are sure, that the input value's format will always be the same, the function above will do just fine. If you're not sure about the format, I would go with one of the great tool libraries others suggested.

**Update:**

You could use the `formatDate` function in your code like this:

```
function checkrecord(reptdate) {
    if (reportdate != '' ){
       $('#tblearn tr[id]').each(function () {
          var _v_reptdate = $.trim($(this).find('[colname = "daterpted"]').html());
          _v_reptdate = formatDate(_v_reptdate);
          if (reptdate == _v_reptdate)  {
             alert('do something');
          }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: I did and I corrected a mistake in your code (it was missing a semicolon). The function I wrote should work nicely. Did you try it? Check my updated answer.

Comment: I don't have access to code today, but i'll try this tomorrow and firstly I need to format reptdate not _v_reptdate and secondly I this I should try this reptdate=formatDate(reptdate, 'mm/dd/yy'); Am I right?

Comment: @user3154990 No, the `formatDate` function I wrote accepts only one parameter - a string of a date in the format you specified, and returns a string in the format you need. Examine my code again and be sure to see it in action using the jsFiddle example I provided.